# How to create separate login for admin and user in django?

Tags: python, django

How to create separate login for admin and user in django using django built in authentication system that user can't access admin panel and vice versa?If admin login it will redirect the admin page and if user login it will redirect the home page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? What were the results, compared to the expected results? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, and knowing the steps you've taken can help us give good, teaching advice (opposed to "here's working code" advice). Please check the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn more about asking good questions.

Comment: If the user doesn't have a staff account, they won't be allowed to access the admin page anyway. Creating a login page is very well documented in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only user who are active and are having staff or superadmin status can login in django admin panel http://prntscr.com/c1kvpx

To enable a non admin user login it is highly recommended that you create a new login page.

Use something like this in your view

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

Have a look at this page in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: Can we use this for a separate admin ? like a  url    127.0.0.1/CustomAdmin and then in user check if its staff member ?